# Use of undeclared type 'DynamicLink'

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Suddenly, I am getting error Use of undeclared type 'DynamicLink'
What is is caused by? The project worked correctly, it just starting acting up for no reason. Last time I modified the pods file was when I installed facebook sdk. I am using  pod FirebaseDynamicLinks (3.1.1)

```
extension AppDelegate {

//    - incoming urls can reach the app in 2 places:

//    1. for universal links we handle those incoming urls in AppDelegate in this method:
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    //check if there is an incoming url
    if let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL {

        //parse dynamic linkUrl into a dynamic link object
        let linkHandled =

            DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingURL, completion: {[weak self] (dynamiclink: DynamicLink?, error: Error?) in

            guard let strongSelf = self else {return}
            if let dynamiclink = dynamiclink,
                let _ = dynamiclink.url {
                strongSelf.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamiclink)
            } else{
                //Else check for errors
                print("error in App Delegate \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })
        return linkHandled
    }
    return false //since I've got nothing that could handle this activity
  }
}


Using Alamofire (4.2.0)
Using AlamofireObjectMapper (4.1.0)
Using Bolts (1.9.0)
Using FBSDKCoreKit (4.38.0)
Using FBSDKLoginKit (4.38.0)
Using FBSDKMessengerShareKit (1.3.2)
Using FBSDKShareKit (4.38.0)
Using FacebookCore (0.5.0)
Using FacebookLogin (0.5.0)
Using FacebookShare (0.5.0)
Using Firebase (5.11.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (5.3.0)
Using FirebaseAnalyticsInterop (1.1.0)
Using FirebaseAuth (5.0.4)
Using FirebaseAuthInterop (1.0.0)
Using FirebaseCore (5.1.6)
Using FirebaseDatabase (5.0.3)
Using FirebaseDynamicLinks (3.1.1)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (3.3.0)
Using FirebaseMessaging (3.2.1)
Using FirebaseStorage (3.0.2)
Using FirebaseUI (5.2.0)
Using GTMSessionFetcher (1.2.0)
Using GeoFire (3.0.0)
Using GoogleAppMeasurement (5.3.0)
Using GoogleUtilities (5.3.4)
Using ObjectMapper (2.2.9)
Using PCAiOSLib (1.0.3)
Using Protobuf (3.6.1)
Using leveldb-library (1.20)
Using nanopb (0.3.901)
Using pop (1.0.10)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked to see if the module is imported?

Comment: No, I hadn't imported it because before FirebaseDynamicLinks was part of Firebase module, they seem to have separated it meanwhile. I have imported it now and it shows no errors now, but it showed with a strikethrough. Is this a bug? https://imgur.com/a/OrzV70j

Comment: I'll admit that's strange to me because strikethrough theoretically means it's already imported. I'll see if anyone knows what might have changed, but in the meantime, if calling it out as a separate import helps, I'd say go for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
let linkHandled  = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingURL) { (dynamiclink, error) in
    // ...
}
```